# HTML select tag without border and providing magic copy

Tags: html, css, copy, html-select

**Background**

I have a text I would like to present on a web page (angular/bootstrap) in which some of the words I would like the user to be able to change by clicking on them, getting a drop-down of fixed alternatives and selecting another one of these alternatives.

**Req 1:**
Ideally it should be a minimal visualisation of whether a word has alternatives or not. Maybe a dotted line under the word.

**Req 2:**
It would be great if the entire text was possible for the user to mark and copy as usual and that the copied result doesn't contain any HTML such as select boxes etc. I realise this req may be impossible to fullfil, but you never know - maybe there are some clever work-around that the clever community has.

I tried using the select tag, but I didn't succeed to fullfil any of the reqs above.

Comment: and where is the code you tried or any jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simpler form for your problem and requirements :

https://jsfiddle.net/aakashshah/2y7kj5j3/1/

`onclick` element can achieve the required feature